# Get date, explode, use data to select options in <select>

Tags: php, date, html-select

I have three variables set, `$date_legible` (in the format of `F jS, Y`, i.e. January 1st, 2011), `$date_timestamp` (self-explanatory), and `$date_normal` (in the format of YYYY-MM-DD)

I have three select fields:

```
    <select name="date_mo">
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="date_dy">
        <option value="01">1</option>
        <option value="02">2</option>
        <option value="03">3</option>
        <option value="04">4</option>
        <option value="05">5</option>
        <option value="06">6</option>
        <option value="07">7</option>
        <option value="08">8</option>
        <option value="09">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select name="date_yr">
        <?php for($year=$curryear;$year<$curryear+51;$year++){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $year; ?>"><?php echo $year; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

I know I want to convert the timestamp, but I will ultimately need to explode the output for the `$month`, `$day`, and `$year`.  The problem is I don't know how to check the selects to the values and automatically select the correct option.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I now have one more variable, because I'm having users submit from the front end, and Gravity Forms submits as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Prior to diving into the solutions already posted (thank you guys [and gals] by the way), here's a little more information:

I'm running WordPress and have three custom fields as described above.  When a user submits a post from the front end, the only custom field that's filled out is `$date_normal`.  This is okay, because a post has to be moderated (i.e. published) from the backend.  What I NOW need is on load to set the `YYYY-MM-DD` to set the options on the `select`.  I'm not asking you guys to alter your answers, I'm sure I can figure it out (though if you can help with this new problem, it would be greatly appreciated).

Comment: I almost understood, but you should explain it a little more. Definitely would help you get better answers.

Comment: Edited my answer to address the update... I think. :)

Comment: Consider `<input type=date>` and let a browser shim handle it.

Comment: @mario, although the site has a HTML5 doctype, the site is more for people who are using Internet Explorer/needs IE compatibility.  I'd rather spend less time using something that works rather than have to build in the compatibility with extra scripting to get IE to work properly.  However, `<input type="date">` is definitely marked down now for later use! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a timestamp and you need to use the timestamp to select the appropriate select options when you render the page.

As a forewarning - this will make it possible to select invalid dates, for example February 31st (does not exist). You may want to consider re-drawing the year drop-down when the month is changed using javascript. Since you didn't specify any javascript library (and it is not clear how important the possibility of an invalid date is), I will not venture to show code for that, but it would not be terribly difficult.

```
// using the current time for the sake of the example, your timestamp would take the place of this
$timestamp = time();

// determine the selected month, day, and year
$selected_month = date('n', $timestamp);
$selected_day = date('j', $timestamp);
$selected_year = date('Y', $timestamp);

// now, create the drop-down for months
$month_html = '<select name="date_mo">';
for ($x = 1; $x < 13; $x++) {
    $month_html .= '<option value='.$x.($selected_month == $x ? ' selected=true' : '' ).'>'.date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1, $selected_year)).'</option>';
}
$month_html .= '</select>';
// output
print $month_html;


// create the day drop-down
$day_html = '<select name="date_day">';
for ($x = 1; $x < 32; $x++) {
    $day_html .= '<option value='.$x.($selected_day == $x ? ' selected=true' : '' ).'>'.$x.'</option>';
}   
$day_html .= '</select>';
// output
print $day_html;


// create the year drop-down
$year_html = '<select name="date_year">';
$start_year = date('Y', time());
$max_year = $start_year + 51;
for ($x = $start_year; $x < $max_year; $x++) {
    $year_html .= '<option value='.$x.($selected_year == $x ? ' selected=true' : '' ).'>'.$x.'</option>';
}   
$year_html .= '</select>';
// output
print $year_html;
```

Output:

[image: Sample of script output]

**EDIT**
If your source data will be in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`. In order to translate that into a timestamp, and thus work with the example code I've posted, is to call `strtotime` on that formatted date value.  Thus, the only line in the code above that would need to be changed is `$timestamp = strtotime($the_formatted_date);`

Comment: your answer is both in-depth and works perfectly for my needs (after tweaking to create a UNIX Timestamp on my own prior to your edit).  Therefore, you get the best answer.  Thank's so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    // $months = array(1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', ... etc
?>
<select name="date_mo">
<? for ($i = 1, $current = (int) date('n'); $i <= 12; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$i;?>"<?=($current === $i ? ' selected="selected"' : NULL);?>><?=$months[$i];?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
<select name="date_dy">
<? for ($i = 1, $current = (int) date('j'); $i <= 31; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$i;?>"<?=($current === $i ? ' selected="selected"' : NULL);?>><?=$i;?></option>
<? } ?>
<select name="date_yr">
<? for ($i = $current = (int) date('Y'), $until = $i + 50; $i <= $until; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$i;?>"<?=($current === $i ? ' selected="selected"' : NULL);?>><?=$i;?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally convert the 3 fields to a more user-friendly date selector (using for example [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)), but to have the correct option selected when you open the page, you need to add a check to each option.

Example for the year:

```
  <?php
      $selected_year = date("Y", $date_timestamp);      // get the selected year
      for($year=$curryear;$year<$curryear+51;$year++)
      {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $year; ?>" <?php echo ($selected_year == $year) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $year; ?></option>
  <?php
      }
  ?>
```